# how to spark left join two datasets (special case)

Tags: sql, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I have two datasets.

The first dataset ONE has fields: uuid, name, latitude, longitude

The second dataset TWO has fields: uuid, lat, long

I want to do a left join in spark between ONE and TWO so that I get the resulting dataset: uuid, name, lat, long (the same type as ONE).

This is because I know ONE.latitude and ONE.longitude will be NULL. I want to fill those fields with TWO.lat and TWO.long respectively.

When I do the left join, the result will be something like this:
uuid, name, latitude, longitude, lat, long

but I want it to be uuid, name, lat, long

I tried this:

```
ONE.joinWith(TWO, ONE.uuid == TWO.uuid, "left").drop("ONE.latitude, ONE.longitude")
```

But I am getting it to be of type Row instead of type ONE. How can I make it to be type ONE?

Answer (score 1):

You can do:

```
ONE.join(TWO, Seq("uuid"), "left")
   .withColumn("lat", col("latitude"))
   .withColumn("long", col("longitude"))
   .drop("latitude", "longitude")
```

This way, you are overwriting `lat` values from `latitude`. If you only want to replace the null values from `lat` and keep what is not null, you can do something like:

```
.withColumn("lat", when(col("lat").isNull, col("latitude")).otherwise(col("lat"))
```

Good luck!